# What does Event.OnDomReady mean and why does it give an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a specific line of code in a js file , which is :

`Event.onDOMReady(myFunction.init);`

Now the thing is : it shows an error in firebug : `Event.onDOMReady is not a function`

When i change the code to :  `window.onready=myFunction.init;`, it works, but throws an error in another function of the js file which is :

`$("#id").observe('blur',myFunction.chek);`

What does this `Event.onDOMReady` mean ? Is there any function like this actually or is it a typo in the file ? What can i do to mitigate the errors that i get ?

Comment: `document.createEvent('Event') instanceof Event` is `true`, so `Event` is some kind of constructor function. Logging it in the console doesn't show any property `onDOMReady`.

Comment: So onDOMReady is not a function of any kind ?

Comment: Not on the `Event` object/function at least.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.